# im trying to build a calculator in java gui

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, jtextfield, calculator

It replaces the `num` variable in text field every time I click a new button. I want it to show every new number one after another when I click different buttons and then eventually I will add/subtract/multiply and divide them and if possible you can give me an idea on how to do math operation on two different blocks of numbers.
your help will be appreciated

```
private class TheHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //add values to buttons
        String num = "";
        if(e.getSource()==btn[0]){
            //tDisplay.setText("7");
            num = "7";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[1]){
            //tDisplay.setText("8");
            num = "8";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[2]){
            //tDisplay.setText("9");
            num = "9";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[5]){
            //tDisplay.setText("4");
            num = "4";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[6]){
            //tDisplay.setText("5");
            num = "5";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[7]){
            //tDisplay.setText("6");
            num = "6";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[10]){
            //tDisplay.setText("1");
            num = "1";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[11]){
            //tDisplay.setText("2");
            num = "2";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[12]){
            //tDisplay.setText("3");
            num = "3";
        }else if(e.getSource()==btn[15]){
            //tDisplay.setText("0");
            num = "0";
        }

        //set the values to the text field

        tDisplay.setText(num);

    }

}
```

Comment: Keep the number area as a string and append digits pressed to the right of the string ,and for arithmatic operations parse the string to integer/double

Comment: Once your application works as intended, you should put the app code up on http://codereview.stackexchange.com for constructive ceiticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
tDisplay.setText(tDisplay.getText()+num);
```

Verifying if 0 was pressed first to avoid a number like this "015"

```
if (tDisplay.getText().equals("0"))
    tDisplay.setText(num);
else
    tDisplay.setText(tDisplay.getText()+num);
```

When you press an operator button must store the value and modify a flag, and when press the equal button store the second value written and perform the operation selected (with the value of the flag).